# Getting Nokogiri to see whether the date is the correct format?

Tags: ruby

So I want to extract the next episodes date from a certain site. The only problem is, if the next episode is today, the selector I use to get the date changes from "MM/DD/YYYY" to "TONIGHT".

This is code i have at the moment (i threw the extra puts date early on to show you how it changes)

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def epnext(siteadd)
    url = siteadd
    nextep = Nokogiri::HTML(open(url))

    title = nextep.at_css('h1').text
    date = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]
    date = date.to_s
    if date.length < 10
        date[0,0] = "0"
    end
    puts date



if date =~ [/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]
    date = date
else
    date = DateTime.now.strftime("%D")
end
    puts title
    puts date
end

epnext('http://www.tv.com/shows/continuum-2012/episodes/')
```

This will output:
05/23/2014 <-before if statement
Continuum
05/18/14 <- after if statement

Basically I want it to interpret the if statement so that if it gets anything but a date it should change the date variable to be todays date.
You can test it out by replacing the "continuum-2012" with "game-of-thrones" (as it airs tonight).

Comment: Sorry, I am not getting, where the problem is.

Comment: @ArupRakshit it should be outputting 
05/23/2014 both times

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did one mistake (*may be copy-paste typo*)

```
if date =~ /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/ # here I removed [], which you put, causing wrong output
  date = date
else
  date = DateTime.now.strftime("%D")
end
```

*Improvement suggestion:*

One more thing you may not notice, that's why you wrote is - `date = date.to_s`. This is not needed, as `data` is holding already a *string* object. `Nokogiri::XML::Node#text` always give a *string* object. Thus you don't need to apply `#to_s` any way.

I think, your method can be re-written as :-

```
require 'nokogiri'
require 'open-uri'

def epnext(siteadd)
  nextep = Nokogiri::HTML(open(siteadd))
  title = nextep.at_css('h1').text
  date = nextep.at_css('.next_episode .highlight_date').text[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]
  puts date
  date = DateTime.now.strftime("%D") unless date =~ /\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/
  puts title
  puts date
end

epnext('http://www.tv.com/shows/continuum-2012/episodes/')
# >> 05/23/2014
# >> Continuum
# >> 05/23/2014
```

Comment: Works absolutely perfect now. Thanks so much. 

Just a question how come we had to remove the []?

Comment: @HarryLucas `text[/\d{1,2}\/\d{1,2}\/\d{4}/]` gives you a `matched string`, that doesn't give you `[matched string]`. Look at the [`#[]`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/String.html#method-i-5B-5D) and read the **4th** paragraph and also see the examples.